# How can I get the actual TCP sequence number in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

In Wireshark, TCP sequence numbers are displayed as relative sequence numbers by default. How can I get the actual TCP sequence number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per [the official Wireshark wiki page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Relative_Sequence_Numbers):

> By default Wireshark and TShark will keep track of all TCP sessions
>   and convert all Sequence Numbers (SEQ numbers) and Acknowledge Numbers
>   (ACK Numbers) into relative numbers. This means that instead of
>   displaying the real/absolute SEQ and ACK numbers in the display,
>   Wireshark will display a SEQ and ACK number relative to the first seen
>   segment for that conversation.

But as explained on that same page, this can be adjusted as follows:

> To disable relative sequence numbers and instead display them as the
>   real absolute numbers, go to the TCP preferences and untick the box
>   for relative sequence numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you require specific directions on where exactly to find the option in Wireshark, like I did, you can can find them at:

**Edit > Preferences > Protocols > TCP**

Uncheck the option: "*Relative sequence numbers*"

NB: I'm using Wireshark 2 and haven't checked if it's the same on other versions of Wireshark. (Chances are that it should be in the same place).