# How can I get the TCP sequence number in Wireshark 1.6.7?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I've seen a almost duplicate [post](https://superuser.com/questions/828294/how-can-i-get-the-actual-tcp-sequence-number-in-wireshark) but the answers did not work for me.

If i go through the path edit>preferences>protocols their is no other options besides display hidden protocol. The first answer on that post I have no idea on how to even get to that screen. While the second answer was the edit>preference>protocols path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand the Protocols by clicking on the '+' expander to the left of Protocols.  From there, you should see all the protocols listed.  You can scroll down to TCP or just start typing "TCP", which will bring you there a bit faster.

Comment: oh wow thank you I didn't even notice that. All that time for that.